# replace text in a file

Tags: sed, mysql, replace

are there any usefull command to replace all text that contain number and remove those number .

Ex:

```
myimages-202x250.jpg
width="202" heignt="250"
```

replace to

```
myimages.jpg
width="217" height="317"
```

i've tried with sed but its not working

```
sed -i 's/*-*x*.jpg/.jpg/g' myfile.sql
```

Comment: `sed` is used regex (BRE or ERE) not globbing `sed 's/-.*x.*\././'`

Comment: i've set a small txt file and use     sed 's/-.*x.*\././' a.txt , but it only show echo and the text in the file doesn't change

Comment: You forgot the `-i` in your last comment. But why talk about `sed` if you want to do it with MySQL?

Comment: while I havenot your test seen I can do any comment. You are free to use http://pastebin.com to show your example file.

Comment: its a wordpress posts i need to mass update , like shown in http://pastebin.com/puwrypw5 . i feel its much easier to dump the database and use sed or replace command to mass replace some text.

Comment: how 202 turns to 217?

Comment: the number is not exact, it can be any numbers

Answer (score 1):

As @Costas pointed out, you are using globbing patterns whereas `sed` uses BRE [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (or ERE if using `sed`'s  `-r` option).

Your command should resemble something like this :

```
sed -i -r 's/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg/.jpg/g' myfile.sql
```

**Explanation :**

- `[0-9]` means "any number" (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
- `+` means "one or more of the previous atom" (The `-r` switch is needed because  `+` only has a special meaning in EREs)

The pattern `-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg` therefore means : "A literal `-` followed by one or more numbers, followed by a literal `x`, followed by one or more numbers, followed by a literal `.` (the backslash is important because `.` is a special character in REs), followed by a literal `jpg`.

**EDIT:**

Upon clarification, this should do what you want :

```
sed -i -r -e 's/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg/.jpg/g' -e 's/width="[0-9]+" *height="[0-9]+"/width="217" height="317"/' myfile.sql
```

The added pattern `width="[0-9]+" *height="[0-9]+"` builds on the same principles as said above and replaces it with the hard-coded string `width="217" height="317"`.

Comment: THANKS!! this should work , i've tested and it worked. any idea how to change width="202" heignt="250" where the numbers is random this with width="217" height="317"

Comment: @juicebyah You want to correct the word `heignt` by the word `height` or you want to replace the width and height by the numbers 217 and 317?

Comment: i want to replace the size of width and height into 217 and 317

Comment: @juicebyah Ok, see the edit section of my answer for a complete answer. Please accept the answer if this suits your need.

Comment: that code works with a small line of txt files , but when i tried to use in mysql files it didnt work. in mysql its shows like this : width=\"233\" height=\"350\"

Comment: ok i figure it out , sed -i -r -e 's/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg/.jpg/g' -e 's/width=\\"[0-9]+\\" *height=\\"[0-9]+\\"/width=\\"217\\" height=\\"317\\"/' myfile.sql , have to add backslash.